# Download completed notification with pending intent

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

Currently I'm notifying the user that the download is completed with this:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    String url = intent.getStringExtra("url");
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
    request.setDescription("Downloading");
    request.setTitle("Bob_Marley-Jammin.mp3");

    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();

    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "Bob_Marley-Jammin.mp3");

    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    manager.enqueue(request);

}

}
```

But when the user clicks on the notification the application force closes. Does anyone know why this is?

What I'd like to happen is when the user clicks the notification a specific activity is launched.

Here's my logcat stuff:

```
06-14 18:27:55.069: E/AndroidRuntime(632): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
06-14 18:27:55.069: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadDrmHelper.getOriginalMimeType(DownloadDrmHelper.java:97)
06-14 18:27:55.069: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadReceiver.openDownload(DownloadReceiver.java:153)
06-14 18:27:55.069: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadReceiver.handleNotificationBroadcast(DownloadReceiver.java:104)
06-14 18:27:55.069: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadReceiver.onReceive(DownloadReceiver.java:74)
06-14 18:27:55.069: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2119)
06-14 18:27:55.069: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-14 18:27:55.069: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1197)
06-14 18:27:55.069: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-14 18:27:55.069: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-14 18:27:55.069: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-14 18:27:55.069: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 18:27:55.069: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-14 18:27:55.069: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-14 18:27:55.069: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-14 18:27:55.069: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 18:27:55.069: E/AndroidRuntime(632): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library drmframework_jni not found; tried [/vendor/lib/libdrmframework_jni.so, /system/lib/libdrmframework_jni.so]
06-14 18:27:55.069: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:393)
06-14 18:27:55.069: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
06-14 18:27:55.069: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at android.drm.DrmManagerClient.<clinit>(DrmManagerClient.java:56)
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Is stack trace the logcat files?

Comment: Yes, please post the exception that was printed to your logcat view when your app crashed.

Comment: I posted it, sorry that it's ugly

Comment: Just use the {} code formatting tool to pretty that stuff up. I submitted an edit and did it for you on this question.

Comment: Are you using JNI of any kind here?

Comment: From what I can see on your stack trace, whatever device you are running this code on is missing the DRM framework library.